usbguard-applet-qt - USBGuard Qt Applet Ubuntu 20.04 installation (cant find it anywhere)
I'm looking for a GUI for USBGuard, just something simple but functional and while I did find this and it does work for me I find it really annoying and just not very functional compared to "usbguard-applet-qt". The problem, however, is, that while I did have this installed on an Arch system about a year ago I'm now on Ubuntu 20.04 and cant really figure out how to install it. I found the (appearently) original github page here and some kind of "reboot" (presumably) here but there's zero documentation. I've also discovered that it used to be part of USBGuard itself but it got removed in v0.7.5 but I dont really feel like using a 5 year old version of USBGuard. I also found this, but when downloading the deb file and trying to install it turns out that
Package libusbguard0 is not installed.
libusbguard1 (1.1.2+ds-6build2) breaks usbguard-applet-qt (<< 1.1.2+ds-6build2) and 
is installed.

I guess I could just remove libusbguard1 and install libusbguard0 but:
usbguard-applet-qt depends on libusbguard0; however:

I don't really know what to do now, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
